# Найти процент использования стороннего кода в Xcode проекте

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, статистика

Как я могу найти процент использования стороннего кода в своем проекте? Необходимо найти не количество кода во всем проекте, деленное на количество кода в Pods директории, а именно количество обращений к коду, описанному в Pods директории.

Например:

- Есть проект в 100 строк кода
- В проекте используется под Alamofire
- Одна из 100 строк кода - это "let method = HTTPMethod.get", которая ссылается на под Alamofire

Результатом исследования будет: 1% использования стороннего кода в проекте

Comment: К чему будет относиться, к примеру, "}" на новой строке, относящаяся к "стороннему" коду?

Comment: @VAndrJ, к стороннему коду будут относиться все классы/структуры/расширения/функции, а так же обращения к свойствам объектов, описанных в Pods.